# Get total cost from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know how to get total cost from this code ..........The PurchaseList class should use an array field to store the purchased items, as well as keeping track of its size (number of items in the list so far).
A PurchaseList class should have the following methods:

PurchaseList( ) //Constructs a new empty purchase list.

public void add(ItemPrice item) //Adds the given purchase item to this list, if the list is not full(i.e., has fewer than 10 items).

public double getTotalCost( ) //Returns the total sum cost of all purchased item in this list.

Write another class named ItemPrice that represents the price of an item according to quantity. The ItemPrice class should store an item quantity and a price per unit. An ItemPrice object should have the following methods:

ItemPrice(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) //Constructs a purchased item with the given name, quantity and price per unit.

public double getCost( ) //Returns the total cost of this item only in its given quantity.

public void setQuantity(int quantity) //Sets this purchase item’s quantity to be the given value.

lastly create test class;

this is my code;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class PurchaseList{

double totalcost = 0;

private ArrayList<ItemPrice> itemlist;

PurchaseList(){
    itemlist = new ArrayList<ItemPrice>(10);
}

public void add(ItemPrice item){

    itemlist.add(item);
}

public double getTotalCost(){
for (ItemPrice pricelist : itemlist) {
    totalcost += pricelist.getCost();
}
return totalcost;
}
}




class ItemPrice{
String name;
int quantity;
double pricePerUnit;

ItemPrice(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit){
    this.name=name;
    this.quantity=quantity;
    this.pricePerUnit=pricePerUnit;
}

public double getCost(){
    return pricePerUnit*quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity=quantity;
}
}


    public class TestPurchase{
    private double item;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    PurchaseList test = new PurchaseList();

    ItemPrice itm =new ItemPrice("Milo",4,20.00);
    ArrayList<ItemPrice> itemlist= new ArrayList<ItemPrice>();
    itemlist.add(itm);
    System.out.println(itm.quantity+" item(s) of "+itm.name +" is RM "+itm.getCost()+". Each item is priced at RM " + itm.pricePerUnit);

    ItemPrice itm1 =new ItemPrice("Milk",4,5.00);
    itm1.setQuantity(1);
    itemlist.add(itm1);

    System.out.println(itm1.quantity+" item(s) of "+itm1.name +" is RM "+itm1.getCost()+". Each item is priced at RM " + itm1.pricePerUnit);

    System.out.println("The Total cost of item in this list is RM "+test.getTotalCost());
  }

  }
```

thank you!!!!!!

Comment: So your `getTotalCost` method will need to declare a variable to use as a running total.  It will also need a loop (an extended for loop would be best) where you iterate through the items, adding the costs to the running total.

Comment: By the way, if you use a `double` variable to store an amount of money, you run a serious risk of getting floating point precision errors when you start adding and multiplying.  You might like to consider using `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `itemlist` is `null` (and you don't initialize it in your constructor), so this

```
private ArrayList<ItemPrice> itemlist;
```

should be something like

```
private List<ItemPrice> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can either keep a running total as items are added to the list like

```
public void add(ItemPrice item){
    itemlist.add(item);
    totalcost += item.getCost();
}
```

**or** you could iterate the `ItemPrice`(s) and calculate the total when `getTotalCost()` is called.

```
public double getTotalCost() {
    double total = 0;
    for (ItemPrice ip : itemlist) {
        total += ip.getCost();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: and not telling us what that problem is ISN'T the best way to get help with solving it.

Comment: i already improve my code but it still display 0.0 for my total cost....P.s           I already edit my code so please help me again

Comment: Why are you creating a second arraylist in your test class? Hint, you're not using.purchaselist.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have an accessor method, getCost() you could use that and add each value in the arraylist to a variable. That variable could then be used to return a totalcost of all the itemprices in your arraylist.

```
 public double getTotalCost()
 {
     double totalcost = 0;
     //BE SURE TO START TOTAL COST AT ZERO OR IT CANNOT ADD UP!!!
     for(int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++)
     {
         totalCost += itemlist.get(i).getCost();
     }
     //DON'T DO IT IN THE FOR LOOP OR THE RETURN STATEMENT WILL STOP IT!
     return totalCost;
 }
```